# How to define size of a button in Excel 2013 using customUI editor

Tags: excel, vba, ribbonx

I am trying to create a new ribbon with 2 buttons in Excel 2013. I was able to create it using Custom UI editor thanks to 
[Excel CustomUI ribbon layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15509769/excel-customui-ribbon-layout) and [How to add a custom Ribbon tab using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850836/how-to-add-a-custom-ribbon-tab-using-vba/8852767#8852767)

When I input the code as

```
<button id="aa" label="CORE"  onAction = "HMA_CORE"/>
```

it works but once I try this code

```
<button id="aa" label="CORE" size = "large" onAction = "HMA_CORE"/>
```

and then click validate in the customUI it says that "size attribute is not declared". I am not sure what to add. I saw http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win009.htm as well, but the code looks the same. 
Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks

The code for the buttons looks like this

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
   <ribbon>
      <tabs>
         <tab id="toolRibbon" label="HMA-FUNCTIONS">
            <group id="groupDocument" label="HMA-xml outputs">
               <buttonGroup id="a">
                  <button id="aa" label="CORE" onAction = "HMA_CORE"/>
                  <button id="ab" label="PLANT" onAction = "HMA_PLANT"/>
               </buttonGroup>
            </group>
         </tab>
      </tabs>
   </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Comment: please show more lines, from `<group id="...>` to `</group>`

Comment: you can only use `size="large"` if the button is under `<group>`, if it is under `<menu>` then put `itemSize="large"` in the menu line.

Comment: @PatricK: I have not used the <menu> tag in my code (I have added the full code). But just in case I tried 'itemSize = "large"' , but I get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try using built in icons from Office (get rid of `buttonGroup`)

[image]

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
   <ribbon>
      <tabs>
         <tab id="toolRibbon" label="HMA-FUNCTIONS" insertBeforeMso="TabHome">
            <group id="groupDocument" label="HMA-xml outputs">
                  <button id="aa" label="CORE" imageMso="MacroArguments" onAction = "HMA_CORE" size="large" />
                  <button id="ab" label="PLANT" imageMso="PictureBrightnessGallery" onAction = "HMA_PLANT" size="large" />
            </group>
         </tab>
      </tabs>
   </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Reference: [Office 2007 Icons Gallery](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=11675)

Comment: That worked well. Thanks! However any idea why button group did not work?

Comment: `buttonGroup` is meant to consume minimal space and join the buttons together, just like the default's Bold, Italic, Underline... on home tab Font group.

Comment: Oh, okay so using a 'Buttongroup' prevents the user from re-sizing the button size.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was the space between the "size" and the "larger" statement! put it all together

error >> size = "larger"

correct >> size="larger"